# How can I read .txt file from S3 bucket using python and view the contents?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

```
data = s3client.get_object(Bucket='', Key='')
data1 = data['Body']

data2 = json.load(data1)
data2 = json_normalize(data=data2)
data2 = sor.explode('header.head')
data2 = data2.to_dict('records')
data2 = json_normalize(data2)
```

I am using the above code for json files to unnest complex jsons and analyse data. How can I do the same to stream text files and view the contents.

```
data = s3client.get_object(Bucket='', Key='')
data1 = data['Body']
with open(data1) as sample: 
    for line in sample: 
        print(line.rstrip())
```

I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not StreamingBody
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you would use [iter_lines](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody.iter_lines) or [iter_chunks](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html#botocore.response.StreamingBody.iter_chunks). For example:

```
data = s3client.get_object(Bucket='', Key='')

for line in data['Body'].iter_lines(): 
    print(line)
```

Note that `line` will be `bytes`, not `str`.

Comment: what about csv files how can we import them?

Comment: @DineshKumar Glad it worked out. I don't understand what do you mean by csv? The same, line by line. You can make new question with new details and/or error messages if you have them.